# Some startup items not working after Debian Jessie upgrade

Tags: debian, startup

I followed [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release/) to upgrade to Debian Jessie.

Since upgrading, sabznbdplus & plexmediaserver are no longer starting on startup. They can both be started by running their files in /etc/init.d/

sabnzbdplus runs from it's python source in a folder in my users home folder, and plexmediaserver is from the unofficial source listed in their forums.

Does anyone know where I can start looking for the issue?

*Edit*

After running the enable service commands, plexmediaserver is now working on startup but sabnzbplus isn't, here is the output from the stauts command.

```
sudo systemctl status sabnzbdplus.service
● sabnzbdplus.service - LSB: Starts Sabnzbd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-02-11 21:34:12 GMT; 11min ago
  Process: 850 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 11 21:34:12 NAS systemd[850]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus: Exec format error
Feb 11 21:34:12 NAS systemd[1]: sabnzbdplus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Feb 11 21:34:12 NAS systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts Sabnzbd.
Feb 11 21:34:12 NAS systemd[1]: Unit sabnzbdplus.service entered failed state.
```

*edit 2*

```
head /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sabnzbdplus
# Required-Start: networking
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts Sabnzbd
# Description:
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Please include the output of `head /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus` as well.

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: This init script misses the shebang line, I wonder how it could work even before the upgrade. Try inserting `#!/bin/sh` as its first line (see other scripts in `/etc/init.d` for a reference). Or switch to using native systemd units as suggested by GAD3R in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. It was further down in the script, not in the header for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable the [`plexmediaserver.service`](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200273978-Linux-User-and-Storage-configuration) and [`sabnzbdplus.service`](https://github.com/wichtounet/systemd-unit-files/blob/master/sabnzbd.service) at boot :

Check the status:

```
systemctl status sabnzbdplus.service
systemctl status plexmediaserver.service
```

enable the service;

```
systemctl enable sabnzbdplus.service
systemctl enable plexmediaserver.service
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise anything had changed. Do the status commands show the applications current status or do they show the status at startup?

Comment: I did the commands you said, and plexmediaserver now starts at startup, but sabnzbdplus doesn't, any idea where to go from here? I've edited the main comment with information from the status command for sabnzbplus.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made special effort, the upgrade switched you from SysV init to systemd. On one hand this may cause problems for local daemons; on the other it allows you to use systemd tools for troubleshooting. If your init scripts are named `/etc/init.d/A` and `/etc/init.d/B`, the corresponding systemd units will be `A.service` and `B.service`. So as a first step, run `systemctl -n100 -l status A` and `systemctl status -n100 -l B` *as root* to find out their status. If the printed information does not help, share it with us (edit your question to include it). Also run `journalctl` and check `/var/log/syslog` for further clues.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't make a special effort to do anything different at startup. Could this be the reason mdadm isn't sending a startup email either? It used to send an email on startup and now it doesn't, but the service itself does start. I also noticed there are a load of frozen emails in exim4.

Comment: Also, do the status commands show the current status or the status at last startup?

Comment: The `status` command always shows the current status, and optionally the logs emitted during and since the last systemd operation on the unit. You can check those frozen mails with `exim4 -Mvc <message ID>`, but please open another question if you need further help with that.